# Guide for writing MS SQL custom EKM dll for interoperation with key management equipment such as an HSM?

Tags: sql-server

I'm looking for a guide and or sample code so as to be able to tackle the following issue. We want to write a custom EKM dll to facilitate interoperation with MS SQL running on a MS Server.

There is already a question in Stack Overflow relating to this issue. There is a corresponding answer that suggests contacting a named contact in MS but that person has probably left - the email account bounces.

I tried raising this guide / sample code question on MSDN / Microsoft QA.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/587994/are-documents-and-sample-code-reelating-to-writing.html

The response I got noted another question on Stack overflow Q & A.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50620374/creating-sql-server-custom-ekm-cryptographic-provider-dll/51052292#51052292
This suggests that MS don't release an EKM guide so you have to enter into an NDA with them to obtain guidance.
The response also suggested raising the question on GitHub MicrosoftDocs/sql-docs.

I raised a query on GitHub.
https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/sql-docs/issues/6942
The answer I got suggested raising the question on Stack Overflow, MS Q & A or here. Contacting Microsoft support was also suggested and I will do this but first of all I'll need to get some funds together.

Any assistance in this matter will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's not documented because it's difficult, dangerous and not recommended.  Why are you proposing to build your own instead of using an existing one?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback David. I haven't explained myself particularly well. We make a product that serves encryption keys. We would like our product to be able to interoperate with MS SQL running on MS Server so as to provide TDE EKM support. I think this requires us to write our own EKM dll as vendors typically seem to do? Perhaps I am misunderstanding the problem?

Comment: I should further mention that we already supply MSCAPI and CNG provider dlls but I am unclear as to which API calls need to be supported for EKM.

Comment: No, that sounds like a valid scenario.  Although you may _also_ want to integrate with Azure Key Vault, which SQL Server can also use.

Comment: Thanks for clarification that the scenario is valid David. We will certainly look into integration with Azure Key Vault as well. Do you know how we could find out which MSCAPI calls need to be implemented in the provider dll so as to support EKM?

Comment: Looking at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/encryption-hierarchy?view=sql-server-ver15 (EKM architecture) & https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/extensible-key-management-ekm?view=sql-server-ver15 "SQL Server provides data encryption capabilities together with Extensible Key Management (EKM), using the Microsoft Cryptographic API (MSCAPI) provider for encryption and key generation" if our CAPI provider supports asymmetric keypair generation, encrypt & decrypt it should be able to support EKM?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft , I work for an HSM manufacturer and we'd like to develop a EKM Provider. How can we access documentation?

Answer (score 4):

> I'm looking for a guide and or sample code so as to be able to tackle the following issue. We want to write a custom EKM dll to facilitate interoperation with MS SQL running on a MS Server.

In order to get that information you'll need to contact the developer relations in regards to SQL Server for 3rd party items. It's not publically available.

> Contacting Microsoft support was also suggested and I will do this but first of all I'll need to get some funds together.

This won't get you anywhere, it's not a break/fix item. Just to add this for future reference, if you do write your own interface for this and there are issues, contacting support will be a futile experience. Any issues caused by the 3rd party software is the responsibility of the 3rd party software owner. You'll need to play nice in the sandbox you're given.

I've helped debug multiple issues with EKM providers, the most common issues are:

1. Handle Leaks
2. Memory Leaks
3. Error Handling Leading To Crashes/Failures
4. Long Operations - This Causes Delays In SQL Leading To Poor Performance/NYS/Stalled Instances

If you're hellbent on doing it better than the commercially available options, then luck be to you.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions Sean. I fear I may not have explained myself all that well. I refer you to my comment above which hopefully clarifies things.